# How to send the image uploaded in frontend in javascript to AWS S3 in Django？

Tags: javascript, django, amazon-s3

I have a web app, frontend using HTML5, backend using Django.
In the frontend, there's an upload button, which is supposed to upload the image to AWS S3.
Now I could only upload the image using that button, but I do not know how to save it to AWS S3 via Django.
How could I do that？

```
<script>
           function renderCover(value, row) {
            return '<input accept="image/*" type="file" id="files" />\n' +
                '<img id="image" />'
        }

        function handleFileSelect (evt) {
            // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
            for (const file of evt.target.files) {

                // Render thumbnail.
                const span = document.createElement('span');
                const src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                span.innerHTML =
                    `<img style="height: 75px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 5px"` +
                    `src="${src}" title="${escape(file.name)}">`;

                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null)
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm also looking for the solution. One way I tried is to convert the image file to a base64 image. I save the image URL in TextField in Django